# Mondrian MDX error with CDate and DateDiff usage

Tags: mdx, datediff, mondrian

How could be solved problem below?

## ERR: mondrian.olap.fun.MondrianEvaluationException: mondrian.olap.InvalidArgumentException: Mondrian Error:Invalid parameter. expression parameter of CDate function must be formatted correctly

My MDX request:

```
WITH
MEMBER 
    [Measures].[diff] as 'datediff("d",CDate([TimeDim.TimeHir].CurrentMember.Name),now())'
....
```

Comment: When I write date as follow, [Measures].[diff] as 'datediff("d",CDate("October 19, 2014"),now())', it works. Question, how can I change date format which will be acceptable by CDate? I am using, pentaho bi-server 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other member properties:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[diff] as 
'datediff("d",CDate([TimeDim.TimeHir].CurrentMember.MEMBER_VALUE),now())'
```

or

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[diff] as
 'datediff("d",CDate([TimeDim.TimeHir].CurrentMember.MEMBER_key),now())'
```

or

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[diff] as 
 'datediff("d",CDate([TimeDim.TimeHir].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties('Key0', Typed)),now())'
```

---

Edit

This one works for me against `AdvWks` :

```
WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[Date_MEMBER_VALUE] as 
  [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MEMBER_VALUE
MEMBER [Measures].[Diff_MEMBER_VALUE] as 
  datediff("D",CDate([Measures].[Date_MEMBER_VALUE]),now())

SELECT
{
[Measures].[Date_MEMBER_VALUE]
,[Measures].[Diff_MEMBER_VALUE]
} 
ON 0,
tail([Date].[Calendar].[Date],12) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

Edit

From here it looks like `.MEMBER_VALUE` does not exist in Mondrian so try using the above code with just `.VALUE` instead: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/mdx.php

Comment: thank you @whytheq for your help, but when I use "Name" property it gets my value normally. Problem is CDate function takes date only in format "Month DD, YYYY" (October 19, 2014). I couldn't find way to change this format.

Comment: @Bagdat did you try the other properties I suggested? `MEMBER_VALUE` works fine in Microsoft's AdvWrks cube.

Comment: property as MEMBER_VALUE nor MEMBER_KEY not exists. @whytheq MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature '<Member>.MEMBER_VALUE'

Comment: it seems to be bug in pentaho http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?187577-CDATE-format-error

Comment: @Bagdat ok - I did my best to help: not much we can do about bugs

Answer (score -1):

You can use DateSerial function to convert your value to datetime format which is accepted by CDate